# Python screenshot especific tab each time it loads

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, screenshot, screen-scraping

**The problem:** I want to write a Python script that takes a screenshot of a website I have opened in a browser each time it loads.

The thing is that I have a website where there are like 300 exam questions which I can get through, try each one of them and I will have the correction when I submit my answer. I will not have access to this questionnaire after a certain date, but I want to keep the questions (which I could write down, but laziness is strong in me, and want to learn Python).

**The "attempt":** I thought of doing a simple Python script with imgkit to take the screenshots. I'm opened to other suggestions, as imgkit was the first thing I saw while looking for this, and the code looks plain and simple to me:

```
import imgkit

imgkit.from_url('http://webpage.com', 'out.jpg')
```

But I have to provide the url for each webpage, and that will be more tedious than taking a screenshot with OS features, thus I want to automatize it.

**The questions:**

- There is a way to make Python *monitor* a browser tab and take a screenshot each time it reloads (that will be when a new question appears)?
- Or maybe get the tab's URL to pass it to imgkit and take the screenshot.
- Another thing that I saw is that imgkit can generate a "screenshot" from a HTML file. Can Python download the HTML code from a tab I have open in my browser?

Answer (score 2):

[Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) is your friend here. It is a framework designed for testing but it will make what you want really easy.

Selenium allows you to spin-up a web browser and control it. So you can instruct it to go to the web address you want and then do things. Normally you would instruct it to click here, write in a form, etc.

In your case you only want it to open a certain address, take a screenshot, go the the next address and repeat.

[Here](https://pythonspot.com/selenium-take-screenshot/) you have a tutorial on how to do exactly what you want.

The specific code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

#1. Get the driver to manage the web-browser you choose
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#2. Go the the webadress you want
driver.get('https://python.org')

#3. Take a screenshot
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")

driver.close()
```

PS: In order for the tutorial to run you will need to have installed the web driver for Selenium to be able to spin-up and run Chrome. [Here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) are the instructions for that.